# How to Stop Fade on Mouse Hover, Javascript code?

Tags: javascript

This is code I'm trying to apply to my work. How can fade stop when cursor touches div or hover the mouse?

I have tried to find a solution to my problem here, but have not met.

```js
$("#prettyslides > div:gt(0)").hide();
setInterval(function() {
  $('#prettyslides > div:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#prettyslides');
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can clear/set the interval on hover..

```
$("#prettyslides > div:gt(0)").hide();

// Set setInterval() to a variable
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  $('#prettyslides > div:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#prettyslides');
}, 3000);

// Clear on mouse over
$('#prettyslides').on('mouseenter', function() {
     clearInterval(interval);
})

// Set on mouse out
$('#prettyslides').on('mouseleave', function() {
     interval;
})
```

---

..or, you can add a class on hover, which prevents the animation chain from firing:

```
$("#prettyslides > div:gt(0)").hide();
setInterval(function() {
  $('#prettyslides:not(hovered) > div:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#prettyslides');
}, 3000);

$('#prettyslides').on('mouseenter', function() {
     $(this).addClass('hovered');
})

$('#prettyslides').on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('hovered');
})
```